# 'Name' is not defined, but I swear it is? (Python)

Tags: python, qpython

I'm testing out this QPython app on my phone and I have the following code:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*
#qpy:console
#qpy:2

numOne = 1
numTwo = 2

person = str(input("What's your name?")) 
print "Guess what I can do?" 
print "Hello,", person
```

However, it returns an error:

```
> hipipal.qpyplus/scripts/.last_tmp.py"    <
What's your name?jason
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts/.last_tmp.py", line 8, in <module>
    person = str(input("What's your name?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'jason' is not defined
1|u0_a320@hltetmo:/ $
```

Sorry if formatting is off, I am posting this from my phone on the go.

Comment: use `raw_input` instead. `input` evaluates your input as python.

Comment: You swear you have a variable named `jason`? Where did you define it?

Comment: This SO question sums it up pretty nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Python2, `input()` will evaluate input; which means when you type `jason`, it is trying to find a variable called `jason`, and since it doesn't exist, you get the exception. You should `raw_input`, which will return the input as a string:

```
>>> input('hello: ')
hello: jason
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'jason' is not defined
>>> raw_input('hello: ')
hello: jason
'jason'
```

In Python3, it will work as expected:

```
>>> input('hello: ')
hello: json
'json'
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Every class and book I've used has only dealt with Python 2.7! I wasn't aware of the difference in 3, as I just learned print statements now go in parenthesis!